# Can't access UEFI Firmware Options in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, bios, uefi

***This is not a question about accessing UEFI! I am already well aware of how to access UEFI on a working Windows device!***

I wanted to do a new install of Windows 10, so I wiped the disk (from a live USB) and reinstalled Windows 10. Before, I could access the firmware settings. Now, I can't. The option to access it just simply isn't there. The reason the bold sentences are up there are because there are lots of questions asked by people who seem to have the same problem as me, but get answers telling them how to access UEFI (on a working system).

Here is a picture of the advanced options menu on my UEFI:

[image: my uefi]

Here is a picture of the advanced options menu on another computer I have:

[image: other uefi]

How can I fix this?

Comment: This means Windows 10 wasn't installed with UEFI mode enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound How can I install Windows 10 with UEFI mode?

Comment: @AlexQuilliam, go into your computer's firmware (BIOS) and check that UEFI is enabled.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 How do I access BIOS? I've tried all of the usual keys, but I have a laptop, so it just boots too fast.

Comment: In your case 'Startup Options'

Comment: Startup settings doesn't say anything about the UEFI.

Comment: Press Del or F2 immediately after powering on to access BIOS.

Comment: Settings to control the Compatibility Support Module (CSM; the component that enables booting in BIOS mode, aka legacy mode) are notoriously inconsistent from one computer to another. Thus, a detailed answer cannot be given without knowing your computer's (or motherboard's) make and model -- and even then, you'd be more likely to get accurate information on a manufacturer forum.

Comment: I got into BIOS (Fn + F2), but when I enable UEFI, I get an error when I boot up. I checked the partitions on the disk, and the UEFI partition just isn't there. Is there a way I can reinstall it? I had it before, so I know my motherboard supports UEFI.

Comment: The error message was `Default Boot Device missing or boot failed`. Disabling UEFI results in a normal bootup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your motherboard and the way you install Windows 10. But one thing for sure if you don't install Windows 10 via UEFI, then this option won't be available there to choose.

Depending on your motherboard, you can access BIOS and enable UEFI before installing Windows 10. [This article](https://neosmart.net/wiki/enable-uefi-boot/) is an example of how to switch between legacy BIOS to UEFI BIOS.

By enabling UEFI, you will tell Windows 10 to use this mode instead of legacy BIOS as default.

There is also another option you can use, which is to install Windows 10 as normal with legacy. After that, upgrade to the latest update: Windows 10 Creators Update and use its built-in function to convert from BIOS to UEFI. This is [an official information](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/WinHEC/mbr2gptconversion) from Microsoft.

Comment: Another way is to select `Startup Settings`, then click `Accept` button, and hold `Enter` key when rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer is:

Boot installation media the UEFI way if you want to install Windows the UEFI way on a blank disk.

If you boot your installation media using BIOS boot then Windows will partition the empty hard disk in MBR style before starting installation.

UEFI boot options for external media usually have the word "UEFI" in their textual display.

Firmware boot options are usually accessible after using "F12" key on power up or after reboot.

Answer (score -1):

If you need Hardware Virtualization settings and can't find UEFI Firmware settings, then i have a better solution where you don't need to re-install windows 10.

Follow the steps :
 Restart your pc  ->  Press **F10** ->  Go to **Advanced** option  ->  Go to **System Options** ->  There you will find your required option